# how to get the function declaration or definitions using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to get only function prototypes like

```
int my_func(char, int, float)
void my_func1(void)
my_func2()
```

from C files using regex and python.

Here is my regex format: `".*\(.*|[\r\n]\)\n"`

Answer (score 8):

This is a convenient script I wrote for such tasks but it wont give the function types. It's only for function names and the argument list.

```
# Exctract routine signatures from a C++ module
import re

def loadtxt(filename):
    "Load text file into a string. I let FILE exceptions to pass."
    f = open(filename)
    txt = ''.join(f.readlines())
    f.close()
    return txt

# regex group1, name group2, arguments group3
rproc = r"((?<=[\s:~])(\w+)\s*\(([\w\s,<>\[\].=&':/*]*?)\)\s*(const)?\s*(?={))"
code = loadtxt('your file name here')
cppwords = ['if', 'while', 'do', 'for', 'switch']
procs = [(i.group(2), i.group(3)) for i in re.finditer(rproc, code) \
 if i.group(2) not in cppwords]

for i in procs: print i[0] + '(' + i[1] + ')'
```

Comment: @Michal, I believe I had a reason for doing that way but I cant remember at this moment :)

Answer (score 2):

See if your C compiler has an option to output a file of just the prototypes of what it is compiling.  For gcc, it's -aux-info FILENAME

Answer (score 2):

I think regex isn't best solution in your case. There are many traps like comments, text in string etc., but if your function prototypes share common style:

```
type fun_name(args);
```

then `\w+ \w+\(.*\);` should work in most cases:

```
mn> egrep "\w+ \w+\(.*\);" *.h
md5.h:extern bool md5_hash(const void *buff, size_t len, char *hexsum);
md5file.h:int check_md5files(const char *filewithsums, const char *filemd5sum);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that this is not a good idea.  C source is not a regular language.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one should do the work:

```
r"^\s*[\w_][\w\d_]*\s*.*\s*[\w_][\w\d_]*\s*\(.*\)\s*$"
```

which will be expanded into:

```
string begin:   
        ^
any number of whitespaces (including none):
        \s*
return type:
  - start with letter or _:
        [\w_]
  - continue with any letter, digit or _:
        [\w\d_]*
any number of whitespaces:
        \s*
any number of any characters 
  (for allow pointers, arrays and so on,
  could be replaced with more detailed checking):
        .*
any number of whitespaces:
        \s*
function name:
  - start with letter or _:
        [\w_]
  - continue with any letter, digit or _:
        [\w\d_]*
any number of whitespaces:
        \s*
open arguments list:
        \(
arguments (allow none):
        .*
close arguments list:
        \)
any number of whitespaces:
        \s*
string end:
        $
```

It's not totally correct for matching all possible combinations, but should work in more cases. If you want it to be more accurate, just let me know.

EDIT:
Disclaimer - I'm quite new to both Python and Regex, so please be indulgent ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are LOTS of pitfalls trying to "parse" C code (or extract some information at least) with just regular expressions, I will definitely borrow a C for your favourite parser generator (say Bison or whatever alternative there is for Python, there are C grammar as examples everywhere) and add the actions in the corresponding rules.

Also, do not forget to run the C preprocessor on the file before parsing.

Comment: Exactly. No matter how good you make your regular expression, it will always be at best a crude approximation of the processing done by an actual C parser. Why try to reinvent the wheel when there are already tools out there tailored for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I built on Nick Dandoulakis's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/943429/724752) for a similar use case. I wanted to find the definition of the `socket` function in glibc. This finds a bunch of functions with "socket" in the name but `socket` was not found, highlighting what many others have said: there are probably better ways to extract this information, like tools provided by compilers.

```py
# find_functions.py
#
# Extract routine signatures from a C++ module
import re
import sys

def loadtxt(filename):
    # Load text file into a string. Ignore FILE exceptions.
    f = open(filename)
    txt = ''.join(f.readlines())
    f.close()
    return txt

# regex group1, name group2, arguments group3
rproc = r"((?<=[\s:~])(\w+)\s*\(([\w\s,<>\[\].=&':/*]*?)\)\s*(const)?\s*(?={))"
file = sys.argv[1]
code = loadtxt(file)

cppwords = ['if', 'while', 'do', 'for', 'switch']
procs = [(i.group(1)) for i in re.finditer(rproc, code) \
 if i.group(2) not in cppwords]

for i in procs: print file + ": " + i
```

Then

```
$ cd glibc
$ find . -name "*.c" -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 python find_functions.py | grep ':.*socket'
./hurd/hurdsock.c: _hurd_socket_server (int domain, int dead)
./manual/examples/mkfsock.c: make_named_socket (const char *filename)
./manual/examples/mkisock.c: make_socket (uint16_t port)
./nscd/connections.c: close_sockets (void)
./nscd/nscd.c: nscd_open_socket (void)
./nscd/nscd_helper.c: wait_on_socket (int sock, long int usectmo)
./nscd/nscd_helper.c: open_socket (request_type type, const char *key, size_t keylen)
./nscd/nscd_helper.c: __nscd_open_socket (const char *key, size_t keylen, request_type type,
./socket/socket.c: __socket (int domain, int type, int protocol)
./socket/socketpair.c: socketpair (int domain, int type, int protocol, int fds[2])
./sunrpc/key_call.c: key_call_socket (u_long proc, xdrproc_t xdr_arg, char *arg,
./sunrpc/pm_getport.c: __get_socket (struct sockaddr_in *saddr)
./sysdeps/mach/hurd/socket.c: __socket (int domain, int type, int protocol)
./sysdeps/mach/hurd/socketpair.c: __socketpair (int domain, int type, int protocol, int fds[2])
./sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/socket.c: __socket (int fd, int type, int domain)
./sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/socketpair.c: __socketpair (int domain, int type, int protocol, int sv[2])
```

In my case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658747/socket-function-definition) and [this](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/kernel_network/socket.html) might help me, except it seems like I will need to read assembly code to reuse the strategy described there.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression below consider also the definition of destructor or const functions:

```
^\s*\~{0,1}[\w_][\w\d_]*\s*.*\s*[\w_][\w\d_]*\s*\(.*\)\s*(const){0,1}$
```