# Socket function definition?

Tags: linux-kernel

When reading C source code, I see the `socket` function used to open a connection. When I search for the definition of `socket` in the Linux kernel source code (version 3 and above) using `grep`, I can find more calls to `socket` but not the definition.

Where is `socket` defined? Is it defined in the source code of the ethernet card?

Comment: *"Your answer can help most of the students understand the connection establishment through software in my company."* <-- What?

Comment: Why do you need to see the definition of the function?

Comment: While I too question your intentions, here is a link that goes deeper in depth than anyone that can't use google should ever need to go with this: http://www.skyfree.org/linux/kernel_network/socket.html

Comment: Thanks for asking this! It was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The `socket()` function is not a kernel function, it is a `libc` one.

If you want to study `socket()` internals get the code of the `glibc` (or any implementation of the standard C library), not the kernel code.

If you plan to go even deeper than that and study how the kernel implements the sockets mechanism look for the system call `sys_socketcall()`.

Comment: That's not exactly true - socket() is a kernel call rather than a libc one, it's manual page is in section 2 (kernel) rather than section 3 (libc) and as it's behavior is defined by the kernel rather than the C library, it is to kernel code where one should be looking.  All that's in libc is a few lines of code implementing the platform-specific syscall mechanism needed to invoke it, and some traps for oddly configured systems.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this thread is ancient, but I actually had to go look this up because I'm working on a security stack that does 10Gb/s and needed to know how this was implemented. I was able to find the source here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/socket.c