# How to match characters at the beginning of a complex regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, pcre

I have a regular expression (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943391/how-to-get-the-function-declaration-or-definitions-using-regex)) used to match C function definitions in text file. In particular, I'm working on some `git diff` output.

```
f = open(input_file)
diff_txt = ''.join(f.readlines())
f.close

re_flags = re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE
pattern = re.compile(r"""
                      (^[^-+]) # Problematic line: Want to ensure we do not match lines with +/-
                      (?<=[\s:~])
                      (\w+)
                      \s*
                      \(([\w\s,<>\[\].=&':/*]*?)\)
                      \s*
                      (const)?
                      \s*
                      (?={)
                      """,
                      re_flags)
```

`input file` is a some raw `git diff` output generated in the usual way:

```
git diff <commit-sha-1> <commit-sha-2> > tmp.diff
```

The first line `(^[^-+])` in my regex string is problematic. Without this line the regex will successfully match all C/C++ functions in `input_file`, but with it, nothing is matched. I need this line because I wan't to exclude functions that were added or removed between the two repository revisions, and lines that are added and removed are identified as

```
+ [added line]
- [removed line]
```

I've read the docs and I can't seem to find where my error is, some help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- and + are special characters in regular expressions. Try escaping them with slashes - [^\-\+]

Comment: I'm on my phone now so I can't give you a link to the documentation, but if you read it, it is clearly stated that special characters lose their special meaning when placed inside square brackets, `[...]`. However, if `^` is the first character in the square brackets, all characters not in the square brackets should be matched.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091065/negative-pattern-matching-in-python)

Simply change the problematic line

```
(^[^-+])
```

to

```
^(?!\+|\-).*
```

Since we're using the negative lookahead operator `?!`, we have to make sure to include the `.*` at the end of the line, otherwise nothing will match.